# Custom node sync function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

Node offers lots of core functions in 2 flavours, sync and async.

Sync functions like  `fs.readFileSync` are very helpful for when starting an app, eg in the npm package dotenv.

Is it possible to write a custom Sync function that does not require the `async` and `await` keywords thus bypassing the promise and callback hell?

Comment: *"but they cannot be used in class constructs or in the more typical server.js starting point of an app"* Yes, they can, in both cases.

Comment: Incorrect statement removed.

Comment: `Is it possible to write a custom Sync function that does not require the async and await keywords thus bypassing the promise and callback hell?`  That doesn't make sense, you don't have callback hell, or even thenables when using `async` / `await`, that's the whole point of them.

Comment: Yes my question was more geared to not having to use the async or await keywords, but also not to have to use callbacks or promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a custom Sync function that does not require the async and await keywords thus bypassing the promise and callback hell?

Yes. Just have that function only use the Sync versions of any API functions it calls.

If the function **has** to use an async API function or module, then no, you can't (readily) make your own Sync version of it (nor do you want to). You *could* fire off a separate child process to do that async work and wait for it synchronously ([`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options), [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options))... (I don't recall the specifics, but there is at least one npm module that does that for some reason...)

---

> ...but they cannot be used in class constructs or in the more typical server.js starting point of an app...

Yes they can, in both cases. Here's an example:

```js
function somethingAsync() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 400, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  });
}

// Using async/await in a class:
class Example {
  async doSomething() {
    let a = await somethingAsync();
    return a * 2;
  }
}

// Using async/await in a top-level script:
(async () => {
  try {
    const ex = new Example();
    console.log("Waiting...");
    const v = await ex.doSomething();
    console.log(v);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error: ", e);
  }
})();
```

Note that it's important to use the `try`/`catch` around the body of that async function (or use `.catch` on its return value), to avoid getting an unhandled rejection error if the function's promise (remember, `async` functions return promises) is rejected.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Will have to do some reading.. do you happen to know if this is how if this is how `readFileSync` is working under the hood?

Comment: It might be terminology, but isn't `doSomething` a method call, not a class construct.. ?  IOW; function constructors don't return promises, but a method call is what I would use anyway.

Comment: @John: If by "this" you mean "only use Sync versions of API calls," I think the answer is largely "yes." For instance, you can find `readFileSync` [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js). It just uses `openSync`, `readSync`, etc. Some of the lowest-level operations are just implemented synchronously in Node's underlying C++ code, using the sync (rather than async) I/O calls available on the platform.

Comment: @Keith: I take "class construct" to refer to the whole thing; note the lack of "or" on "construct." (Using "construct" for things like `class`, or `for`, or `switch`, is fairly common.) Yes, constructors can't return promises (unless they're promise constructors, of course :-) ), but as you say, in general it would probably be better to wait to start any async process until a method call rather than from within the constructor...

Comment: `I take "class construct" to refer to the whole thing;`, yeah.  it's down to terminology.  I've seen the term class construct to mean constructor, eg. things like jsDoc keyword @constructs uses this.  So I did wonder if that's what the OP meant when he said class construct, or if he meant the class syntax construct.  Either way it certainly doesn't stop him using classes with async / await.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Very helpful

Comment: @Keith: With respect, "constructs" in that context is a *verb*. I've never, once, heard someone use "construct" (the noun) to refer to a constructor.

Comment: I was referring to `constructor()` but it seems this is possible after all.

Comment: I know what your referring too when you say `class construct`, and I don't disagree.  But reading the OP's question, I inferred his meaning of construct, as in to construct an object, aka. constructor.  And looking at the response above, looks like I nailed it on the head.  Like I said at the beginning, `It might be terminology`.  IOW: I'm not disagreeing with you, but was only pointing out potential miss understanding.  And why I said method call.

Comment: @Keith: OMG, I read that as "- Keith", not "- John"! :-) My dodgy eyes...